# Cómo enviar una Lista de pedidos de adapter a fragmento

Tags: java, android

por favor alguien puede ayudarme,cómo puedo enviar una lista de objetos de un adaptador a fragmento.Estoy listando los pedidos de los clientes ,pero como hay clientes que tienen más de un pedido ,al dar Click quiero envíar la lista de pedidos a otro fragmento.agradezco de antemano.
Estoy usando java.

**Este es mi interface.**

```
public interface SendData {
     void sendInfo(List<Pedido> pedidoList);
}
```

Este mi adapter de desde donde quiero enviar al seleccionar.

```
public class ClienteAndPedidoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClienteAndPedidoAdapter.ClienteAndPedidoViewHolder> {
    public List<ClienteAndPedido> lista;
    SendData listener;
    public ClienteAndPedidoAdapter(SendData listener){
        this.listener=listener;

    }
public class ClienteAndPedidoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView clienteNom;
        TextView cantPedidos;
        public ClienteAndPedidoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            clienteNom=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCPclienteNom);
            cantPedidos=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCantPedidos);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    List<Pedido> listita;
                        listita = lista.get(getAdapterPosition()).pedidoList;
                        listener.sendInfo(listita);
                        Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "enviando lista de pedidos x cliente..." + listita, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

Comment: Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar el código que llevas; de otra manera es pura especulación.

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos!